# Icon for a button to move a list item. Not scroll

Tags: buttons, icons, scrolling, drop-down-list, position

In our software we have a dropdown menu. The dropdown menu has listitems which represent columns for a table. Via two buttons in the list (on the left side), the position of the listitems can be changed. The position of the columns in the table will also be changed. The dropdown looks like this:

[image]

Problem: The buttons to move the position accidentally communicate that the list can be scrolled. Reason: The icon is looking like a typical icon for scroll buttons:

[image]

There is also another typical scroll icon we cannot use:

[image]

Question: How can we communicate via icons in the buttons, that the buttons change the position of the selected list item?

Comment: Your question is about Icon suggestion which is not suitable for this site. Sorry. Maybe [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) is the right place.

Comment: Why do you think this topic is not a thing about user experience?

Comment: I have read that in your question.

Comment: Are you open to a UI change, can you afford to change the list with another element?

Answer (score 2):

In this typical example:

[image]

The **Blue Up & Down Arrows** can be clearly differentiated from the scrollbar, and it is intuitive too.

Comment: + it is used by multiple programs like that, so users might already be familiar with it, too

Answer (score 1):

Drag and drop can be quite intuitive if done correctly.

See here for an example: https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/57127/screenshots/1074817/drag_drop-list.gif
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The icons are fine, your problem is that the buttons are too far away from the item it is acting on.

You could make the up and down arrow buttons appear inside the list control, on the selected item itself.

[image]

Comment: Nice Suggestion. One Problem that I can see here: When the user clicks on an arrow via the mouse then the entry moves from the mouse pointer away. So when the user wants to move the entry multiple times (e.g. from position 1 to 10) then the he has to move the mouse pointer over the arrow every time again.

Comment: @Simon Good point. Drag drop is better in this specific case.

Comment: The case pointed out by @simon is pretty valid and important. I would suggest you go with the familiar control (which is my answer) or go with drag and drop if development and design teams could handle.